# Perl passing a constant to a subprogram

Tags: perl, parameters, constants, subroutine

I have the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

# Declare some meaningful named constants
use constant {FOO => 2,
              BAR => 3,
              BAM => 4};

# Define paths between the named entities
my %PATHS = (FOO => {BAR => "Foo->Bar",
                     BAM => "Foo->Bam"},
             BAR => {FOO => "Bar->Foo",
                     BAM => "Bar->Bam"},
             BAM => {FOO => "Bam->Foo",
                     BAR => "Bam->Bar"});

# Printing out PATHS map does more or less what I expect:
foreach my $src (sort keys %PATHS) {
  foreach my $dst (sort keys %{ $PATHS{$src} } ) {
    print "$src:$dst\t$PATHS{$src}{$dst}\n";
  }
}

# I can't use the constants as parameters
sub findPath($$) {
  my $src = shift;
  my $dst = shift;

  print "src:$src\ndst:$dst\n";
  my $path = $PATHS{$src}{$dst};
  print defined $path ? "path=$path\n" : "UNDEFINED\n";
}

findPath(FOO, BAR);
```

It appears that my constants are treated as barewords and implicit quotes are added within the declaration of the HoH PATHS.  Is there an easy way to define such a map where the symbolic keys are usable across function invocations?

Answer (score 2):

The `=>` operator does two things:

1. quotes the bareword on the left
2. acts like a comma

If you only want #2, just use a comma.

Comment: Of course!  Sometimes you get so habituated to one way of doing things that you forget the details of what your doing.  Initializing a hash with anything other than {x => y} looks wrong, even it it's right.

Comment: I know what you mean. It feels good to imagine that perl has a syntax specifically for compile-time building of hash literals (in which `=>` is the key/value separator, and that the comma is only used between pairs) but that's just an illusion.

Comment: Know your secret operators: the [winking fat comma `,=>`](https://github.com/book/perlsecret/blob/master/lib/perlsecret.pod#winking-fat-comma-) disables bareword quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Perl constants are really just subroutines that take no parameters and return a fixed value.

That means you can add the `&` prefix to *force* them to be interpolated:

```perl
my %PATHS = (&FOO => {&BAR => "Foo->Bar",
                      &BAM => "Foo->Bam"},
             &BAR => {&FOO => "Bar->Foo",
                      &BAM => "Bar->Bam"},
             &BAM => {&FOO => "Bam->Foo",
                      &BAR => "Bam->Bar"});
```

And keep the nice `=>` syntax that shows the key => value relationship.

You can also use the old `@{[...]}` trick which will always work:

```perl
print "The value of constant FOO is '@{[FOO]}'\n";
```

Which is easier to parse with your eyes than this:

```perl
print "The value of constant FOO is '" . FOO . "'\n";
```